# How do I associate a string array with an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I am just new to coding and trying to write a basic program.

I want to generate an array of random numbers(each under 50) and then associate these numbers with a string array(of names) that has been populated by the user.

I need it to work so that each name is allocated a score when the random int array is generated. I then need to keep track of the score for each name in the string array and when one name gets to a certain score they are the winner.

Any help would be massively appreciated as I am just beginning.

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: What do you mean by associate? That's generally a term used with relational programming.

Comment: Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: To be honest I don't not have much to go on. I have written the code to generate the random array and I need each number of the random array to to be added to each name in the string array as a score.

Comment: private int[] generateRandomNumber(int numberOfPeople)
 {
  int[] randomArray = new int[numberOfPeople];
  for(int i=0; i<numberOfPeople; i++)
  {
   randomArray[i] = rand.nextInt(MAX_SCORE+1);
  }
  return randomArray;

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways of doing this, the best I would think is to create a class for it.

```
class Player {
    String name;
    int score;
}
```

Then in your main code where you generate the random numbers keep an Array of players. `Player[] players;`

Alternatively you could use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` but using Objects lets you expand more easily in the future.

Comment: OP is just a beginner. Trying to overwhelm with HashMaps is not a very good idea.

Comment: I still can't get it to run. Basically I have gotten the user to populate a string array with names. I have then written the code to generate a random array of numbers under 50. I then want to each spot in the int array to correspond with a name in the string array. 
When one name reaches a certain score I want to Print out there name as the winner. I then want to print out the names that did not reach the score and what score they did get.

Comment: @fugi08 So what you want to do is instead of adding a name into a String array and the score into a separate Integer array, you want to add those values into the Player class, then add the Player into Player array.

Comment: Okay, so keeping it basic and doing it how you do currently. When you add in a value to say position `4` in your score array, make position `4` in the name array equal to that person. Then when you want to check who the winner is you just loop through one array, once you find the player with the highest score, you take that index and do something like: `System.out.println(names[i]);` to get their name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by declaring a random number generator, then implement it into a 2d array. 
`Random a=new Random();`
Filling the array using a loop, with `int num=a.nextInt(50);`
`String array[i][0]=a` after a being converted to a String, and `array[i][1]` being the names.
This should make tracking the results easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a TreeMap perhaps to map the numbers to the string array.